# Extending Ractive component when using a loader

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I've been trying to get around using component loaders as described in [component spec](https://github.com/ractivejs/component-spec/blob/master/authors.md). I am unsure how can I do something like this via a component file:

```
var bookmarkableBaseClass = Ractive.extend({
    oninit : function(){
        this.on(commonBookmarkEvents);
    },
    data : {
        badgeDefinitions: globalCommonBadgeDefinitions
    }
});

Ractive.components.singlecard = bookmarkableBaseClass.extend({
    template: "#smallcarditem"
});

Ractive.components.singleline = bookmarkableBaseClass.extend({
    template: "#cardlineitem"
});
```

In other words - have a component which extends another base component with common properties - ie common data as well as common proxy event handlers. Currently the component spec only allows me to include other components but not have inheritance as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not something that's currently supported, though it [has been discussed](https://github.com/ractivejs/component-spec/issues/10). I think the best option looks like this:

```html
<div class='singlecard'>
  <!-- template goes here -->
</div>

<script>
  var bookmarkableBaseClass = require('./bookmarkableBaseClass');

  component.exports = {
    base: bookmarkableBaseClass,

    someSubclassMethod: function () { /*...*/ }
  };
</script>
```

Any existing component loader could be modified easily enough to facilitate this – which are you using?

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer this. I am currently using rvc as a loader.